# Hex Dump String without whitespace

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, xxd

I want to convert a string into a hex using xxd.

The problem is that it adds a "0a" at the end of the hex.

**Command**:

```sh
echo "hello world" | xxd -p
```

**Output**: 68656c6c6f20776f726c640a

**Expected**: 68656c6c6f20776f726c64 (without the 0a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x0a` is the hex value of an ASCII newline.

`echo` produces a new line at the end, so you got trailing `0a`.

To avoid this, use `-n` parameter:

```
echo -n "hello world" | xxd -p
```

Or, you can use `printf`:

```
printf "hello world" | xxd -p
```